# Information stored in a cookie file

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Thanks for you help in advance.

I am trying to figure out the structure of the cookie file, more specifically i want to be able to determine the expiry time.  From the cookies i have created they all appear to be in a standard format.  Name, Value, website,followed by 5 numbers and a star.  See example below.

name
value
www.website.co.uk/
1536
3041141504
30135951
1632526096
30135949
*

Obviously the expiry time is one of the numbers, the question is which one. From experiments I have determined that the first and fifth number don't seem to change.  In a case where i generated three cookies at the same time with a 1000 second time difference i noticed that the fourth number appeared to increase by 2000 suggesting that this has a connection with the expiry time.

Can anyone confirm if i am heading in the right direction?  And does any one know how i convert this to a human time and date(preferably in php but any language would give me a starting point)

thanks
Jason

Comment: What OS and browser do you use?

Comment: Gumbo,  I am using Win 7 with ie8.

Comment: To reply to Gumbo and have him get notified, use `@` followed by at least three (I think) characters of his name (as I did here with yours, although technically I didn't need to). Otherwise, he won't get notified unless he reply to a question or answer of his.

Comment: @Gumbo, I am using Win 7 with ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out the answer.  Thanks to everyone who responded.

The format of the the cookie in ie8 is:
name
value
website
flags-not entirely sure what this is
expiration time (low)
expiration time (high)
creation time (low)
creation time (high)
To convert these numbers into actual times you can use the following formula:
time = 1*10-7*(high*2^32+low)-1164447360

thanks again

Jason

Comment: @Gumbo i found the info at [link] (http://weitips.blogspot.com/2006/04/cookie-file-format-of-internet.html).  sorry for the late response

Comment: Well, as it seems that you answered your question yourself, how about accepting it?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to figure out the structure of the cookie file...

There isn't one. It's entirely up to the browser where and how to store cookies on the client computer. You can certainly solve this for popular browsers, but it won't be the same solution for all of them. Some store cookies in flat files; others store them in *individual* files (per cookie, or per site), others as SQLite databases...

Comment: Thanks for your response, didn't know they all had different formats.  I am using ie8 on win 7.  I don't want to create a script to read the information from the cookie so the fact that all browsers store them differently should cause me a problem.  I want to determine how long they will last before they expires so that i can get my script to create them again.